Help with proof of Curl Double Product identity using Geometric Algebra. Most things seem to fall in place, but having a few issues.
So I'm pretty new to GA/Clifford Algebras, but it's been fairly interesting so far. I figured I'd try to prove some basic vector calculus identities with it, just to help me get my bearings. I decided first to try the "curl double product" identity, generally written as
$$\nabla\times\nabla\times F = \nabla (\nabla\cdot F) - \nabla^2F$$
I remember this being hell when trying to prove it with standard dot/cross product rules in Griffiths. I first though to rearrange a bit, since the gradient is redefined/re-contextualized in GA.
$$\nabla (\nabla\cdot F) = \nabla\times\nabla\times F + \nabla^2F$$
Now, the gradient is treated as a geometric product in GA/GC, so equivalently we can write
$$\nabla (\nabla\cdot F) = \nabla\cdot(\nabla\cdot F) + \nabla\wedge(\nabla\cdot F)$$
I'll leave the left term alone for now, as it is the cause of my troubles.
$$\nabla\wedge(\nabla\cdot F) = (\nabla\wedge\nabla)\cdot F \text{ (I think)}$$
$$ = -(\nabla\times\nabla)^*\cdot F$$
Now, since $\nabla\times\nabla$ is a vector, its dual should be a bivector in $\mathbb{G}^3$. $F$ is a vector/vector field. Then, if you multiply the two terms, and move all of the terms of $F$ to the left side, it will take 2 swaps for every element of F. Thus, doing so will leave the sign unchanged
$$ = -F\cdot(\nabla\times\nabla)^*$$
$$ = -(F\wedge(\nabla\times\nabla))^*$$
$$ = -F\times(\nabla\times\nabla)$$
$$=\nabla\times\nabla\times F$$
So we're left with
$$\nabla(\nabla\cdot F) = \nabla\cdot(\nabla\cdot F) + \nabla\times\nabla\times F$$
And this is where I'm stumped. Everything seems to almost work out. But if I'm not mistaken, the divergence term doesn't collapse to the Laplacian? What am I missing here?
I have considered the identity $\textbf{A}\cdot \textbf{B} = \textbf{AB}$ if $\textbf{A}\subseteq\textbf{B}$. However, as far as I am aware, this only holds for blades no?

I'm sorry, but almost all your manipulations are wrong. What are you learning GA from? As a side note, this identity is easy to prove using the BAC-CAB rule (which is essentially how you do it with GA as well) as long as you understand how to use $\nabla$ properly (many don't). See my answer here.

Thanks for commenting. I do understand how you would use the BAC-CAB rule. However, I'm more using this as an exercise to try to get myself familiar with GA manipulations. If you wouldn't mind please point out where I went wrong. I'm learning GA from Alan Macdonald's two books on GA and GC.

On top of what Peeter Joot says at the beginning of his answer, the equation where you say "(I think)" is false, and I don't know why you think it would be true; actually the RHS is identically zero unlike the LHS. When you say "...take 2 swaps for every element of F. Thus, doing so will leave the sign unchanged" I'm not really sure what you're talking about; the product is a dot (contraction) product between a bivector and a vector, which is antisymmetric: $$-(\nabla\times\nabla)^*\cdot F = F\cdot(\nabla\times\nabla)^{*}.$$

You also misapply the cross product formula (missing a minus sign), which is
$$
a\times b = -(a\wedge b)^*
$$
assuming $X^* = XI$ with $I$ the right-handed unit pseudoscalar. Finally, you treat the cross product as associative when it is not.

Thank you. I'm only really about a week in to learning this stuff, and as a physics major I'm used to sloppy math... After posting this question I went and derived the triple product from the Laplacian instead,$$\nabla^2F = \nabla(\nabla\cdot F + \nabla\cdot A) $$

Lol I meant $\nabla^2F = \nabla(\nabla\cdot F + \nabla\wedge F)$

You write:
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla} (\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{F}) = \boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{F}) + \boldsymbol{\nabla}\wedge(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{F}),$$
but it appears that you are trying to use the vector identity
$$\mathbf{a} \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b},$$
(true for vectors $ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} $), but not neccessarily for multivectors.  In your case $ \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{F} $ is a scalar, not a vector, so there is not really any meaningful reduction that you can make of $ \boldsymbol{\nabla} (\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{F}) $.
The essense of the identity you are trying to find is given by the following manipulation
$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{a} \times \left( { \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} } \right)&=-\left( { I \mathbf{a} } \right) \wedge \left( { \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} } \right)  \\ &={\left\langle{{-\left( { I \mathbf{a} } \right) \wedge \left( { \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} } \right) }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=-{\left\langle{{I \mathbf{a} \left( { \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} } \right) }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=-{\left\langle{{I \mathbf{a} \left( { -I \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} } \right) }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=-{\left\langle{{\mathbf{a} \left( { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} } \right) }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=-{\left\langle{{\mathbf{a} \cdot \left( { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} } \right) +\mathbf{a} \wedge \left( { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} } \right) }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ &=-\mathbf{a} \cdot \left( { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b} } \right) \\ &=-\mathbf{a}^2 \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a} \left( { \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} } \right).\end{aligned}$$
Notes:

In this case, it's also true that $ \mathbf{a} B = \mathbf{a} \cdot B + \mathbf{a} \wedge B $ for bivector $ B $ and vector $\mathbf{a} $.  Here the dot and wedge products have the following meanings:

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{a} \cdot B &= {\left\langle{{ \mathbf{a} B }}\right\rangle}_{1} \\ \mathbf{a} \wedge B &= {\left\langle{{ \mathbf{a} B }}\right\rangle}_{3}.\end{aligned}$$

Also observe that we are free to insert a no-op grade-one selection around any vector without changing the meaning.  That allows us to discard the trivector term of the vector-bivector product.

We also used the distribution identity


$$\mathbf{x} \cdot \left( { \mathbf{y} \wedge \mathbf{z} } \right) = \left( { \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} } \right) \mathbf{z} - \left( { \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{z} } \right) \mathbf{y}.$$
If we summarize what we've done, essentially, we've first observed that
$$\mathbf{a} \times \left( { \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} } \right)=-\mathbf{a} \cdot \left( { \mathbf{b} \wedge \mathbf{c} } \right),$$
for any vectors $ \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c} $.  In particular
$$\mathbf{a} \times \left( { \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{F} } \right)=-\mathbf{a} \cdot \left( { \mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{F} } \right) = -\left( { \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{a} } \right) \mathbf{F} + \mathbf{a} \left( { \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{F} } \right),$$
This also holds for the case where $ \mathbf{a} = \boldsymbol{\nabla} $, provided we take care to keep the gradients on the left (or use notational sugar to indicate the scope of their action.)

Thank you. This was really informative. I'm only around 2 week into studying up on GA, but it's been very enlightening. I hope to continue on, and eventually start using it in my studies of physics in the future.

It seems that David Hestenes' site (geocalc.clas.asu.edu) isn't working anymore. Do you know where else I can read his works?

Okay, another user pointed me to the Wayback Machine. I suppose this link will be useful for others like me.
